# Counting substrings in a list of strings

Tags: python

For example:

```
my_list = ["item*1", "item*2", "item*3", "item*4"]
```

I'd like a way to search for "item" and return 4 as item appears 4 times regardless of the extra characters.

Comment: You must iterate through the list and search in each string item for `"item"`.

Comment: use `str.find()` method while iterating the strings in the list. or the `in` operator.

Comment: what if there's `itemitemitem`? would you want that to return 1 or 3?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way I could come up with is this:

```
sum(map(lambda x: 'item' in x, my_list))
```

```
Out[1]: 4
```

It basically sums the `True` returned every time `item` is found in an element of `my_list`

Comment: But this one does not find multiple occurrences

Comment: Since posting my answer I asked OP what behavior he expects for multiple occurrences. He has yet to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use count, checking each element in your list

```
my_list = ["item*1", "item*2", "item*3", "item*4"]

a = sum([el.count('item') for el in my_list])
print(a)
```

Update:

If you want "item" counted only once if it appears multiple times within elements of your list, the solution is even simpler.

```
a = sum(['item' in el for el in my_list])
```

Comment: that will not return the right number if `item` is present twice in the same element

Comment: Yes, it would. `count`counts the number of occurrencies

Comment: yes, that's what it does

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this in 2 ways. the first with the '`in` operator and the second with the `str.find()` string method. and if your search is `case insensetive` use the `str.lower()` string class method.

```
count = 0
for word in my_list:
    if 'item' in word.lower():
        count +=1

print(count)
```

or using the `str.find()` method but the `in` is prefered

```
 count = 0
for word in my_list:
    if word.lower().find('item') != -1:
        count +=1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a lambda function which will return the no of times the "item" appeared in a list or sequence.

```py
count = lambda li: sum([i.count('item') for i in li])
print(count(["item*1", "item*2", "item*3", "item*4"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `list` into `str` and then use `count` method on the string to count the occurrence of the desired word in this case *"item"*

```py
my_list = ["item*1", "item*2", "item*3", "item*4", 'itemitemitem']
count = ' '.join(my_list).count('item')
print(count)
```

This will work even if any *"item"* occurs more than one time like *"itemitemitem"*

Answer (score 0):

```
data_is = ["item*1", "item*2", "item*3", "item*4"]
count = 0
for each in data_is:
  if 'item' in each:
    count = count +1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ["item*1", "item*2", "item*3", "item*4", "item-oh-item-oh-item"]
n = 0
pattern = "item"
for str in my_list:
    n += str.count(pattern)
print(n)
```

I added an extra string to show why I use `count`. If the pattern could be overlapping, like searching for "coco" in "cococo", I would use regular expressions from the package `regex`, not the standard package `re`.